RIP Charles Ingrid
Charles Ingrid, probably best known for the "Sand Wars" series (with their attention-grabbing Vincent Di Fate covers), passed away July 29th.
Ingrid, whose legal name was Rhondi A. Vilott Salsitz (see also Wikipedia), also published several fantasy series (over 40 novels in total) under a number of other pen names, including the Dragontales game books as by Rhondi Vilott.  Other works published under the Ingrid name include the "Marked Man" duology and the "Patterns of Chaos" series, all with covers by Di Fate.
(The covers of these books have stuck in my memory, but I haven't actually read them despite the recommendation of a friend of mine back in the 1990s.)
